# Is there a way to loop through 3 lists with the same values and not repeat some of the output? (Python)

Tags: python

For example, here are three lists:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list2 = ['a','b','c','d']
list3 = ['a','b','c','d']
```

Is there a way to get the following output?

```
a b c
a b d
a c d
b c d
```

This way it won't repeat any 3 outputs already used once again.

Comment: Please explain little bit more. Why using three lists and what type of output you want? Because this type of output can be generate with single list.

Comment: I did not understand why you use 3 same lists but you can achieve such thing with itertools.permutations e.g. `print(list(permutations(["a","b", "c", "d"], 3)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested loops and play with the indexing:

```py
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list3 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(list2)):
        for k in range(j+1, len(list3)):
            print(list1[i], list2[j], list3[k])
```

But what happens when you add one more list? You need to go and put another loop.

---

You can get this output from only one list, using the [`combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html). The `r` argument is the equivalent for how many lists you have:

```py
import itertools

list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
for tup in itertools.combinations(list1, 3):
    print(*tup)
```

Gives:

```
a b c
a b d
a c d
b c d
```

Comment: What about 3 lists?

Comment: @AdamStrauss The question has 3 lists with the same values. Effectively, we need to get from said lists to said outputs.

Comment: @AdamStraussd there you go

Comment: Yeah I used the first way in the beginning, and you explained it very well. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use permutations to get all possible outputs

```
import itertools

lis =['a','b','c','d']
x= itertools.permutations(lis)

print(list(x))
```

If the ordering does not matter and you want to ensure elements selected are not repeated irrespective of the position , you can use combinations functions as below

```
import itertools

lis =['a','b','c','d']
x= itertools.combinations(lis,3)

print(list(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 3 lists to get your desired result. [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) does this for you.

```
from itertools import combinations

list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
result = list(combinations(list1, r=3))
```

Result:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd'), ('a', 'c', 'd'), ('b', 'c', 'd')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a dictionary *vals*, now while looping through each list add the value as an "index" of vals thus ONLY example 
`val[lista[i]] = lista[i]`
`val[listb[j]] = listb[i]`
`val[listc[k]] = listc[i]`

Then finally print the values of the *vals*, thus printing the required.